# Not getting sensor reading from fragment class

Tags: android, android-sensors, sensormanager

I am trying to get `sensor` gyroscope reading from a `fragment`

I implemented the `SensorEventListener`

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, SensorEventListener

private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mSensorGyro;
float [] history = new float[2]; 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensorGyro = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);

}
```

Here's how I handled on incoming sensor readings.

```
  @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSensorChanged: ");
        switch (sensorEvent.sensor.getType()) {
            case Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE:

                float xChange = history[0] - sensorEvent.values[0];
                float yChange = history[1] - sensorEvent.values[1];

                history[0] = sensorEvent.values[0];
                history[1] = sensorEvent.values[1];

                if (xChange > 2) {
                    //clockwise
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSensorChanged: Clockwise");                        
                } else if (xChange < -2) {
                    //anticlockwise
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSensorChanged: Anti-Clockwise");                        
                }
                if (yChange > 2) {
                    //forward
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSensorChanged: Forward");
                }
        }
    }
```

When I run it on my android device, I am not getting any reading back, judging from the missing log on android logcat.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Missing listener register

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorGyro, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```